# std::this_thread::sleep_for time resolution

Tags: c++, sleep, c++-chrono

So I'm helping my buddy out with some code and we've hit some weirdness in the sleep_for function:

This works, gives an "acceptable" timing of about 16.7ms (acceptable being +/- 2-4ms, but anyway):

```
int main()
{
    long double milliseconds=16.7*1000;

    auto start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long double, std::micro>(1670));
    auto end=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Slept for: "<<std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(end-start)<<std::endl;
}
```

This however, will only give you a minimum of 30ms, works as expected above 30ms:

```
int main()
{
    long double milliseconds=16.7*1000.0;

    auto start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long double, std::micro>(milliseconds*1000.0));
    auto end=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout<<"Slept for: "<<std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(end-start)<<std::endl;
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

I've tried various castings and different periods, they all end up about the same.
Using milliseconds period and above causes a minimum of 30ms, microseconds and below have expected results.

I suspect that there are different code paths that does different clock resolutions and bottoms out or something like that, but why doesn't a variable being multiplied by 1000 to go from 'ms' to 'us' not work?
I don't get it.

Comment: 1670 us are not 16.7 ms. `std::chrono::duration<long double, std::micro>(milliseconds*1000.0)` is a duration of `16.7*1000.0*1000.0` us, which is 16.7 seconds.

Comment: Oops, yeah... Totally right, but the question still stands, putting in 16700us nets 30ms timing while 1670us gives 16.7ms timing.

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: This is on Windows, using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Adding `timeBeginPeriod(1)` can help with this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod The default resolution is ~15ms. There should be no difference in the two programs you've shown assuming you fix the incorrect values used in both.

Comment: Yep, that does appear to do it. Sometimes I hate Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a Windows API "quirk", calling timeBeginPeriod will set minimum period resolution not only on Win32 API calls that deal with timing, but also stdlib.

The timing with this code is nearly perfect on Linux, naturally.

Thanks to Retired Ninja for the answer!